# Castle Class Proxy for unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, castle-dynamicproxy

Scratching my head how to do this.

Suppose I had a concrete class `Foo` with 2 virtual methods, `Execute()` and `GetFile()`.  `Execute()` will call `GetFile`.  I want to make sure that when it does, `GetFile()` will throw a couple of different exceptions that `Foo` is supposed to handle gracefully in a testable manner.

For my unit tests, I am envisioning instantiating a DynamicProxy<`Foo`> from castle project where I intercept the `GetFile()` to throw the exception, and then invoke the DynamicProxy object's `Execute()` method, and test the results, but I can't see how to do this.

Is this possible/ practical?  If so, what would the creation of the dynamic proxy object look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to handcode your own proxy because most the mocking frameworks support your scenario.

Here is an example using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) (Moq will create a dynamic proxy internally for you):

```
public class SomeException : Exception { }

public class Foo
{
    public virtual int Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            GetFiles();
        }
        catch (SomeException)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public virtual void GetFiles()
    {
        //...
    }
}

[Test]
public void FooTest()
{
    var fooUnderTest = new Mock<Foo>();
    fooUnderTest.CallBase = true;
    fooUnderTest.Setup(f => f.GetFiles()).Throws(new SomeException());
    var result = fooUnderTest.Object.Execute();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result);
}
```

You just need to take care to set `Callbase = true` which will:

> Invoke base class implementation if no expectation overrides the
>   member (a.k.a. "Partial Mocks" in Rhino Mocks): default is false.

Comment: Outstanding.  Exactly what I was looking for.